# How to create menu like with animation scale?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a PSD like this.

[image: menu]

I want to create like https://www.khaneyeax.com/en/ site, And When I put the mouse on the link, a circle will appear on the link. And I use bootstrap 4.5.

CSS

```
ul.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding: 60px 0 16px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 110px;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li > a > i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
    right: 0;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

ul.navbar-nav > li:hover:before {
    transform: scale(30);
}
```

a simple Html HTML

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-th-large fa-2x"></i>
        <span>Home</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I see this demo.

[image: demo]

Comment: Is there anyone who can answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

Add a **hover** function to the **a** tag

```
.nav-link:hover {
   border-radius: 50%;
   border:1px solid red;
   padding:15px;
 }
```

change the border color according to you wish

Comment: You tested it before. I see this demo https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPHMY.png

Comment: I added everything, even Bootstrap, for example,      What code should I add?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to have a hover function to the `<a>` tag. I have given a sample below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Top Navigation Example</h2>
  <p>Some content..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know, how to create a menu. I want to create a menu only like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/R46Ko.jpg   .  And  like this site https://www.khaneyeax.com/en/